# all purpose try/catch block method

Tags: php

In the PHP project I'm working on there are several methods that make use of individual try/catch blocks.  Here is one example:

```
public function getListData()
{
    $clauses['filter'] = '';
    $clauses['sort'] = 'CAST(propertyID AS INT) DESC';
    try
    {
        return $this->getModel()->getListData($clauses);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // create an Error() object, send $e->getMessage() to it
    }       
}
```

Now, keeping in mind there are several similar methods, it would seem more efficient to write a method in the Model class that would look like this:

```
public function run($method)
{
    try
    {
        return $this->$method;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        //create an Error() object, send $e->getMessage() to it         
    }
}
```

The problem is calling it.  This does not work:

```
public function getListData()
{
    return $this->getModel()->run('getListData($clauses)');
}
```

The error is:

> **Undefined property:
>   classes\utility\Model::$getListData($clauses)**.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: It is already in getListData().  Imagine 50 methods similar to getListData(), but with different functionality.  There are try/catch blocks everywhere so the desire is to funnel everything through a single generic try/catch block method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the first and second `getListData()` methods are in separate classes, otherwise you are calling a loop, since `getListData` would call `getListData`...which would call, you get it.

However, the way you are calling the method is incorrect in the `run()` method. It should be called using [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). It is a callback to the method, not a call to the property, of the class.

You could call it statically using

```
public function run($method, $data)
{
    try
    {
        return call_user_func(array($this, $method), $data);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        //create an Error() object, send $e->getMessage() to it         
    }
}

public function getListData()
{
    return $this->getModel()->run('getListData', $clauses);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that assumption is correct.  After copying/pasting the line above in the try block it is now giving a warning: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'classes\utility\Model' does not have a method 'getListData($clauses)'   which makes no sense because getListData($clauses) is in the Model class.  Got any ideas?

Comment: Does your `getListData` function in the `Model` class expect a parameter to be passed to it? Is it `getListData($clauses)` or `getListData()`? Additionally, you'll want to read up on the `call_user_func` function. With this code, you'll want to declare it as `public static function getListData($clauses)`

Comment: In the Model class the method is getListData($clauses).  In the Model class I changed it to public static function getListData($clauses).  Now it says call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'classes\utility\Model' does not have a method 'getListData($clauses)'.

Comment: Updated the answer to account for sending data to the callback. That should work for you.

Comment: Yes!  That worked but I had to take the word static out of public static function getListData($clauses) in the Model class.  Thanks very much Adam!

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with this approach:

1. It prevents you from listening for custom exceptions

   You can throw exceptions other than `Exception`, but this type of wrapper will make it much more difficult to do so.
2. It is difficult to follow the execution flow

   When you pass method names and parameters around as strings, it becomes much harder for humans, IDEs and code analysis tools to understand what the program will do at runtime.
3. Try/catch blocks are cheap

   The code required to catch exceptions is very simple and easy to use. This wrapper adds more complexity and more cost (an extra function call).

Consider just using try/catch blocks where needed instead of using the wrapper. If you have fifty similar methods as described in your comment above, you may gain more efficiency by eliminating the duplicate business logic and combining those methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply convert errors to exceptions using this code:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
        {
        if ((error_reporting() & $errno) === $errno)
            throw new \Exception("$errstr ($errfile: $errline)", (int) $errno);
        }, -1);
```

After it any error would be converted to exception.